# SQL Query SELECT,ORDER

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-order-by

**SQL Query SELECT,ORDER date**

Hi, I need to select the date from my table, the problem is that I have above 130 rows and it will grow every day. I want to short it and in the query to select the date that equal for today `date=date("Y-m-d")` and the date that bigger from the date of today.

It can be a variable the date of today because I'm using a date selection to paginated between the dates. I know I can use timestamp but I dont know how to implement it in the query.

```
  $r = mysql_query("SELECT  date FROM yoman  ORDER BY date ASC,time ASC  ") 
            or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope you will unserstand, http://attiatech.com/projects/tours/index.php?db=cmVsXzIwMTI= this is the link, try to pick the 1.10.2012 and see how many rows are printed, i have the second option of view paginated but i want in this query to filter it too.

Comment: Can you outline the structure of your table, i.e. the columns with their types?

Comment: I hope you will unserstand, http://attiatech.com/projects/tours/index.php?db=cmVsXzIwMTI= this is the link, try to pick the 1.10.2012 and see how many rows are printed, i have the second option of view paginated but i want in this query to filter it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you store the date as string "Y-m-d".

It might be better to use this though as table column type:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

So e.g.:

```
$startdate= date("Y-m-d", $day); 
$enddate= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", $day)) - 1;
```

SQL to fetch one day goes like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yoman 
WHERE date BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate 
ORDER BY date ASC,time ASC
```

Comment: One can also paginate using the mysql limit clause: LIMIT $pos, 10 but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking this:

```
set @dte=sysdate();

select sysdate()
SELECT  date 
FROM yoman  
where date>=@dte
ORDER BY date ASC,time ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the rows with today and future date you can use directly a sql query without php, just use [curdate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) otherwise if you use `sysdate()` `current_timestamp` `etc` it will check also the time and you do not want it because if you launch the query at 10am, you don't get all the rows before 10am of the day...

`SELECT date FROM yoman WHERE date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC`

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT  date FROM yoman  ORDER BY date,time ASC
```